# How to make <aside> function as a column containing content

Tags: html, css

As my title states I have a website I am trying to divide into essentially three columns.  The first column on the left would contain the < nav> bar and the largest column would be the center content area containing paragraphs, images, etc...

Then for the right-most column I need it to be an < aside> element that is the same height as the other columns and the same width as the < nav> column which is about 50% of the column containing the majority of the content. My issue is I simply don't know how to configure the margins, paddings, etc in order to get this type of layout. I have done my best so far but can't get the aside element to appear as a column.   Here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Juniper Lane Swimming Club Inc., Bridgewater, NJ 08807</TITLE>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <img src="header.jpg" alt="header">

        </header>


    <nav>
        <ul>

          <li><a href="http://www.jlsc.org">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="pool-info.htm">Pool Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="news-events.htm">News &amp; Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="swim-team.htm">Swim Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="swim-lessons.htm">Swim Lessons</a></li>
          <li><a href="jlsc-board.htm">JLSC Board </a></li>
          <li><a href="photo-gallery.htm">Photo Galleries</a></li>
          <li><a href="links-htm.htm">Useful Information</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
          <main>
        <img src="hp-1.jpg" id="hp1" alt="pool" width="241" height="172"><h2 style="color: blue;">Welcome to Juniper Lane Swim Club!</h1>
            <p>Juniper Lane is the neighborhood club where family fun is #1!</p>
            <p>Whether you're looking for a place to take the kids, swim a few laps <br>
          to stay in shape or just relax on a lounge chair with a good book - Juniper Lane is the place for you.<br>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <img src="hp-3.jpg" id="hp3" alt="bench" width="237" height="172">


                <p class="greebtext">About Us - </p>
                  <p>The Juniper Lane Swim Club is a member owned non-profit, private swimming club located in Bridgewater, NJ.</p>
                  <p>The club was established in 1955 but the facility has been renovated and well-maintained over the years</p>
                  <img src="hp-2.jpg" id="hp2" alt="poolslide" width="237" height="172"><br>
                  <p>We maintain a membership of 180 families strong. Although we are currently at our maximum, we maintain a waiting list of families who are interested in joining the club. We are typically able to accomodate a number of new families each year through normal attrition. If you are interested in a JLSC membership or information please send an email to 
                  <!-- Start email --> 
                  <script  type="text/javascript" 
src="http://www.jlsc.org/code/java/email/email.js"></script>
                  <!-- End email -->.</p>
                <p>We are located on Juniper Lane in Bridgewater Township, just 
off Country Club Rd about 1mi north of Garretson Rd.</p>



 </main>
 <footer>
 <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2017 Juniper Lane Swim Club</i></small>
  <small></a></small>
 </footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

And Here is the CSS:
    Body {
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#59b3d2;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("pool-water.jpg");




}





.redbtext {
    color: #a90000;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.greebtext {
    color: #39780a;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
}

.greebbullet {
    color: #39780a;
    font-size:13px;

}
.bluetext {
    color: #013370;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
}

nav {float: left;
width: 190px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #ffff80;
}

nav a {text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;}

nav a:link {color:#blue;}

nav a:hover {color: orange;}

nav a:visited {color:#002266;}

li {list-style-type: none;}


main {margin-left: 210px;
background-color:#ffffcc;
height: 100%;
font-size: 1.1em;
color: grey;

padding-right: 200px;
}

#wrapper {width: 967px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #ffff80;
overflow: hidden;


}

footer {text-align: center; 
padding: 20px;
}








#hp1, #hp2, #hp3 {border: 10px solid white;
float:right;}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask questions that are most likely to get you good help. In your case here, we need to see your style.css file to see what you've got going so far and what you might be able to change to fix your problem. We just need the CSS relevant to defining the columns, not all the styles for your site.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the 3 column heights the same and you can get away with [supporting IE 10+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), flexbox can achieve this: https://codepen.io/pixleight/pen/RZgxYP/

```css
#wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header,
nav,
aside,
main,
footer {
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  /* outline just for visibility purposes */
  outline: 1px solid #F0F;
}

header,
footer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 100%;
  -ms-flex: 100%;
  flex: 100%;
}

nav,
aside {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  -ms-flex: 2;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.jlsc.org">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="pool-info.htm">Pool Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-events.htm">News &amp; Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="swim-team.htm">Swim Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="swim-lessons.htm">Swim Lessons</a></li>
      <li><a href="jlsc-board.htm">JLSC Board </a></li>
      <li><a href="photo-gallery.htm">Photo Galleries</a></li>
      <li><a href="links-htm.htm">Useful Information</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h2>Welcome to Juniper Lane Swim Club!</h1>
      <p>Juniper Lane is the neighborhood club where family fun is #1!</p>
      <p>Whether you're looking for a place to take the kids, swim a few laps <br> to stay in shape or just relax on a lounge chair with a good book - Juniper Lane is the place for you.</p>
      <!-- truncated for brevity -->
  </main>
  <aside>
    <h3>Aside</h3>
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2017 Juniper Lane Swim Club</i></small>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @pixleight would be the approach I would take but if you don't want to use flexbox, you can simple use:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 33%;
vertical-align: top;
box-sizing: border-box; /* where the magic happens, takes the paddings into account for the width size */
float: none; /* to reset the floats on your code */
```

You can check it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/1jnnyb4d/

A few notes on your code that I noticed:
1) you have a lost "h1" closing tag on your main element (should be an h2, I think) and a lost "a" closing tag on your footer;
2) color:#blue; is not a a valid CSS instructions (either you use just "blue" or an HEX value).